# How to save temporary data that will be erased when system reboot

Tags: android

i want to save a Boolean data that will be lost on system reboot.

I`ll use that to verify if all of my App notifications was scheduled on system boot. I dont know a way to do it. I basically want to lose this boolean data when system is rebooted.

I have a BroadCast receiver for OnBoot of device that reschedule all notifications , but i want to assure that this code of OnBoot will really run on system boot, if it does not run I`ll have to know this, and reschedule all of my notifications. How can i register some data until system is rebooted ?

Comment: "i want to save a Boolean data that will be lost on system reboot" -- Android does not have anything for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the boolean variable in a file by using FileWriter.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
```

After Importing:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("filepath");
//There are 3 different write methids you can use. Go to 
//the java official documentation to see them.
```

To read:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
```

After Importing:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("filepath");
```